# Nexus 3 Proxy to virtual maven 2 repository

Tags: java, maven, nexus

We moved from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3 and face the problem of still need to support some artifacts uploaded by projects still working with Maven 1.

In Nexus 2 I was able to setup a Maven 1 repository (**N2-P-M1**) and I configured a virtual Maven 2 repository (**N2-V-M2**) by which it was able to download the artifacts from a Maven 2 project.

Now with Nexus 3 there is no native support for Maven 1 repositories. So I kept the Nexus 2 running and configured a Maven 2 proxy repository in Nexus 3 (**N3-P-M2**) that is meant to be a proxy for the virtual repository in Nexus 2.

But unfortunately I see no assets in Nexus 3 for that proxy (N3-P-M2).

I observed that when browsing the virtual Maven 2 repository in Nexus 2 there are only JARs and POMs but no metadata files. This may be a problem for Nexus 3 I suppose.

Comment: Are you really need Maven 1 repos ? Migrate those build to Maven 3.... Sorry to say.....Or you have to stuck to Nexus 2 ...Sorry to say but why is someone using such  ancient stuff ? And to be honest I don't see problem for Nexus 3  ...I see the problem keeping such ancient stuff life instead of migrating it to more recent things...that will solve your issue...and you can go completely to Nexus 3...I hope you are using a recent version of Maven 3.3.9 or Maven 3.5.0 ? I hope not Maven 2 anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the Layout Policy to permissive instead of strict, if you haven't already on the Nexus Repo 3 side. That will allow pretty much any path to pass through. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but it might be worth trying it out.

Shy of that working, please file an issue with us at our JIRA: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS . Since you are proxying what SHOULD be a Maven 2 repository, I'd like to know personally what the issue is.